# Java, prepareStatement, SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, FoundRows() hows it work

Tags: java, mysql, pagination, sql-calc-found-rows

I'm trying to do pagination from the db and so far I have found that if you want to use limit you should use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

However, in Java I'm having some issues understanding how to call this.

Can I do it in one prepareStatement or will I need to make multiple calls? If im making multiple calls, how does MySQL know I'm referring to the last call for the count?

Thanks.

Comment: Please tell us what you want to achieve. Do you want to use the limit clause in a SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to make two calls (unless you implement a some stored function in the db which returns both the limited resultset and the count, which I assume is possible in mysql but never tried that).

MySQL will know what query counts to return because both the query with the limit and the `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` will be in the same session.

Comment: Is there any risk of `found_rows` being associated with a different query (eg: if two queries are called one right after the other)? I call  `ps = connection.prepareStatement(originalQuery)` then process the result set, then call `ps = connection.prepareStatement(totalRowsQuery)` then process its result set. Any risk of query being called in the same session at the time I am processing the original query?